# Is is possible to subscribe to alarms with a OPC UA client?

Tags: c#, opc-ua

I have Siemens panel TP1200 Comfort in which there are many alarms.

I have used UAExpert to connect to the server, and I can navigate through the tags, but I am not able to see the way the to navigate to do it through the alarms.

My idea it is if I could subscribe to the alarms, so if I implement a OPC UA client with C#, I could handle it, send some email or save the data in a database.

For the client, I am trying to use the library from OPC Fundation: https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard.

Thanks.

Comment: I have also looked into this.  AFAICT, alarms are not supported in the Comfort panel's OPC UA server

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. The UAExpert can e.g. subscripte to events and alarms.
[You can find the doc here](https://documentation.unified-automation.com/uaexpert/1.6.3/html/event.html)

I think the .net stack also can do it because its the reference implementation in C# but I could not found an example.

Edit: Here is an Example for AlarmConditions [UA-.NETStandard Alarm Condition Sample](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard-Samples/tree/master/Workshop/AlarmCondition)